# How to delete repeated values writen twice consecutively in start of every year (in shell script)?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, calendar

I have a 10years (1970-1979) daily dataset which has repeated values at the start of each year. I mean to say the values are as in following example:

```
3   (January 01, 1970)
2   (January 02, 1970)
3   (January 03, 1970)
5   (January 04, 1970)
.   ................
.   ................
.   ................
4   (December 30, 1970)
2   (December 31, 1970)
2   (January 01, 1971)    Here it is repeating the preveous years value
3   (January 01, 1971)    
5   (January 02, 1971)
2   (January 03, 1971)
3   (January 04, 1971)
.   ..................
and so on
```

**Kindly note here: The second column i.e. the above mentioned date is not available in the original data. I have mentioned here just to describe my problem.**

The original data looks like:

```
3
2
3
5
.
.
and so on
```

I was trying to copy one by one as per calander and skiping January 1 value. My following script is working. But I can't able to write a general good script.

```
 for add in 366, 731, 1097, 1462, 1827, 2193, 2559, 2924, 3289, 3654;do
 sed -i ''${add}'d' data.txt
```

expected output is:

```
3
2
3
5
.
.
.
4
2   here the repeated value has been deleted
3
5
2
3
.
and so on
```

Comment: Whats your expected output ?

Comment: @AkshayHegde.. The repeated value should be deleted from each year. I have edited the question.

Comment: @anubhava.. How the cut command will recognize that? I have the datasets only in ascii form i.e. like 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n.......

Comment: Your sample data shows spaces after 1st column. Is that not correct?

Comment: You have identified correctly. The second column is not there in the original data. I have writen to describe it.

Comment: You have to provide better data and clearly describe the problem. Question says `1971-1980` but data starts with `January 01, 1970`

Comment: Oh yes!! it is a typo. Actually from 1970-1979.

Comment: So there are 356 or 366 lines per year?

Comment: It is as per leap year.. so 365 as well as 366

Comment: @anubhava.. the following one is working, but i need a general script. `for add in 365, 730, 1095, 1461, 1826, 2192, 2557, 2922, 3287, 3653;do
 sed -i ''${add}'d' data.txt`

Comment: @Kayan: What do you mean by *need a general script*? A script which works for any range of years, not just 1970-1979?

Comment: Yes!! I need a general script which can work for any period. Because if change my period from 1971-1980, then the above manual script will not work.

Comment: Well, for each given year, you know whether it is a leap year or not. Hence, given the starting year of the period, you can calculate the list of line numbers, which need to be dropped. Put this into an `awk` program, which runs once through your input data, and you are done....

Comment: @Kayan: I have posted such a solution. I tested it a little bit, but please verify that it doesn't have one of those infamous +/- errors.

Comment: Why oh why do people put `....`s into their examples???? Just give us something concrete we can run a potential solution against to test it, not a bunch of `...`s cluttering up the examples and making them untestable. I for one have absolutely no idea what it is you are trying to do given your posted sample input and expected output. I can't even tell for sure what's really in your files and what you've added for decoration.

Comment: 365th day is not Jan 1st.  You're deleting the last day of the year Dec 31st.  Your leap day counter is not consistent 1970: 365, 1971: 365, 1972: 366 (leap year). So first 3 numbers in the series should be 365,730,1096, and the rest is wrong as well.

Comment: @karakfa .. Yes you are right. It will start from 366, 731, 1096 and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
uniq YOURFILE >COMPACTEDFILE
```

UPDATE: I misunderstood the original question, and my suggestion does not make sense.

Comment: How it will work? I have only ascii data.. no date information

Comment: It removes all duplicates. I assumed that if you would have a duplicate line in the middle of the year, you want to have it removed too. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Kayan: Sorry, now I see that I completely misunderstood your question, and that you have clarified, that you don't have the second column. Of course my solution doesn't make any sense then.

Comment: @user1934428 if your solution doesn't make sense then deleting it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk:

```
awk 'NR !~ /^(365|730|1095|1461|1826|2192|2557|2922|3287|3653)$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following solution? It would fail for the year 2100, but you can easily fix this:

```
function is_leap_year(year) {
  return year % 4 == 0
}
function skip_count_for_year(year) {
  return 365 + (is_leap_year(year) ? 1 : 0)
}
BEGIN {
  current_year=from
  skip_after=skip_count_for_year(current_year)
}
{
  if(skip_after > 0) {
  skip_after--
  print
} else {
  current_year++
  skip_after=skip_count_for_year(current_year)
}
```

}

The program would be called by, i.e.

```
gawk -f yclean.awk -v from=1995 YOUR_INPUT_FILE
```

I tested it with gawk, but I think it should also work with awk and nawk.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!  between 1901-2099 this logic will work, otherwise you have add 100 and 400 leap year rules

```
$ awk -v start=1970 -v end=1979 'BEGIN{for(i=start;i<=end;i++) 
             {sum+=365+(i%4?0:1); skip[sum]}}
             (NR in skip)' <(seq 10000)
365
730
1096
1461
1826
2191
2557
2922
3287
3652
```

negate the condition and it will only print other lines.

```
$ awk -v start=1970 -v end=1979 'BEGIN{for(i=start;i<=end;i++) 
             {sum+=365+(i%4?0:1); skip[sum]}}
            !(NR in skip)' file
```

also see my comment under the original post!

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to improve your original manual solution (I assumed that it was good.)

```
cat dld.sh

#!/bin/bash
(($#!=3))&& { echo "Usage $0 start_year end_year file_name"; exit 1; }
for((y=$1; y<=$2; y++)); do
   ((add+=y%4?365:y%100?366:y%400?365:366));
   echo "Deleted line :$((add+1))"
   sed -i ''$((add+1))'d' $3
done

./dld.sh 1970 1979 tmp.txt
Deleted line :366
Deleted line :731
Deleted line :1097
Deleted line :1462
Deleted line :1827
Deleted line :2192
Deleted line :2558
Deleted line :2923
Deleted line :3288
Deleted line :3653
```